# Merge multidimentional array if parent id same then merge child data

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert below array.

Criteria is,

If `projectId` same then store same project id data under array of project which contains `projectId` as key.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PMST] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [project_id] => 25
                    [task_name] => Final task 3
                    [start_date] => 2016-06-21 00:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-06-29 00:00:00
                )

            [PMSP] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 25
                    [project_name] => Project 3
                    [start_date] => 2016-06-01 00:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-06-04 00:00:00
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PMST] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [project_id] => 28
                    [task_name] => Task Test 333 edit
                    [start_date] => 2016-06-19 00:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-06-29 00:00:00
                )

            [PMSP] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 28
                    [project_name] => Project Employee Test
                    [start_date] => 2016-06-10 00:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-06-30 00:00:00
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [PMST] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [project_id] => 28
                    [task_name] => Task 1
                    [start_date] => 2016-06-01 00:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-06-04 00:00:00
                )

            [PMSP] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 28
                    [project_name] => Project Employee Test
                    [start_date] => 2016-06-10 00:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-06-30 00:00:00
                )
        )
)
```

**Desire Output**

```
Array
(
    [25] => Array
        (
        [PMSP] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 25
                    [company_id] => 1114701
                    [project_name] => Project 3
                    [start_date] => 2016-06-01 00:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-06-04 00:00:00
                )
        [taskdetails] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array(
                  [PMST] => Array
                      (
                          [id] => 4
                          [project_id] => 25
                          [company_id] => 1114701
                          [task_name] => Final task 3
                          [start_date] => 2016-06-21 00:00:00
                          [end_date] => 2016-06-29 00:00:00
                      )
                )           
            )
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
          [PMSP] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 28
                    [company_id] => 1114701
                    [project_name] => Project Employee Test
                    [start_date] => 2016-06-10 00:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2016-06-30 00:00:00
                )
          [taskdetails] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                  (
                [PMST] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 9
                        [project_id] => 28
                        [company_id] => 1114701
                        [task_name] => Task Test 333 edit
                        [start_date] => 2016-06-19 00:00:00
                        [end_date] => 2016-06-29 00:00:00
                    )
                )
                [1] => Array(
                [PMST] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [project_id] => 28
                        [company_id] => 1114701
                        [task_name] => Task 1
                        [start_date] => 2016-06-01 00:00:00
                        [end_date] => 2016-06-04 00:00:00
                    )
                )
            )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over your input array using `foreach`, adding the `PMST` data to an output array as you go. It looks like it's safe to assume the `PMSP` data for two tasks on the same project will be the same.

```
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $task) {
    if (!isset($output[$task["PMSP"]["id"]])) {
        $output[$task["PMSP"]["id"]] = ["PMSP" => $task["PMSP"], "taskdetails" => []];
    }
    $output[$task["PMSP"]["id"]]["taskdetails"][] = $task["PMST"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Its working perfect. :) +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 2):

See the below example

[Example](https://eval.in/590958)

```
$data = [];

foreach ($a as $b) {
    $key = $b["PMSP"]["id"];
    if (!isset($data[$key])) {
        $data[$key] = ["PMSP" => $b["PMSP"], "taskdetails" => []];
    }
    $data[$key]["taskdetails"][] = $b["PMST"];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);exit();
```

Your latest data
[Example 2](https://eval.in/590960)